# SQL - Round up a date/time to the coming Sunday

Tags: sql, oracle, date

Looking to round up half hour interviews to the coming Sunday. My query has a column (titled Trading Interval) with date and time stamps such as `02/03/2020 08:30` and `29/02/2020 19:00`.

I want to generate a new column titled Week Ending that rounds these dates/times up to the coming Sunday.

So for the date `29/02/2020 19:00` it would round up and return `01/03/2020 00:00` and for the date `02/03/2020` it would round up to `08/03/2020 00:00`

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `TRUNC` to trunacate the date back to midnight and then `NEXT_DAY` to get the next sunday:

```sql
SELECT trading_interval,
       NEXT_DAY( TRUNC( trading_interval ), 'SUNDAY' ) AS week_ending
FROM   your_table;
```

So, for the test data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE your_table ( trading_interval ) AS
SELECT DATE '2020-03-02' + INTERVAL '08:30' HOUR TO MINUTE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-02-29' + INTERVAL '19:00' HOUR TO MINUTE FROM DUAL;
```

This outputs:

> ```
> TRADING_INTERVAL    | WEEK_ENDING        
> :------------------ | :------------------
> 2020-03-02 08:30:00 | 2020-03-08 00:00:00
> 2020-02-29 19:00:00 | 2020-03-01 00:00:00
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=885425b657acf0b27ad170d7f6b891c2)*